# .where database query based on attributes of two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 2 models `Member` and `Profile` linked via a `has_one` association where `Profile` `belongs_to` `Member`.

In the DB the members table contains columns `:username` and `:email` amongst others.

`:first_name` and `:last_name` columns are located in the profiles table.

I'm writing a method to execute a search of the members as below:

```
  def self.search(search)
    where("username ILIKE :query OR email ILIKE :query", query: "%#.   {search}%")
  end
```

Currently it works fine retrieving members matching the query to usernames and emails. However, I was wondering if there's a way to modify the method so that it matches as well the query with the `:first_name` and `:last_name` attributes that do not exist in the `Member` model.

I've tried to modify my members_controller using a `joins` method trying to blend both tables and including the `Profile` attributes in the search method without success as below:

The relevant part of the index method in my controller.

```
if params[:search]
  @members = @community.members.joins(:profile).search(params[:search][:query])
else
  @members = @community.members.order('created_at ASC')
end
```

And the modify search method:

```
  def self.search(search)
    where("username ILIKE :query OR email ILIKE :query OR first_name ILIKE :query", query: "%#{search}%")
  end
```

I'd appreciate your guidance.

Comment: why does that not work? error message?

Comment: maybe add table name explicitly? `profiles.first_name` etc

Comment: @Fallenhero the joins method was actually working fine. Sorry I made a mistake while testing it. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach changing the controller with the .join was actually working fine and I had an issue while testing the feature that misled to think it was not working. Sorry!